# Only one thread created with MPI & no speed-up with OpenMP

Tags: linux, mpi, openmp

I actually have two questions but it seems they may be connected:

1) I've tried to run basic MPI example:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    printf("I am %d from %d\n", rank, size);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

It has to output something like:

```
I am 0 from 2
I am 1 from 2
```

Although I'm getting the following:

```
$ mpicc mpi_hello.c -o hello    
$ mpirun -np 4 ./hello          
I am 0 from 1
I am 0 from 1
I am 0 from 1
I am 0 from 1
$ mpirun -np 2 ./hello
I am 0 from 1
I am 0 from 1
```

Is it somehow connected to thread definition in Linux? I'm running it on Ubuntu 16.04.

2) My OpenMP program:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

const int N = 10000;

int matrix[N][N];

int main()
{
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)

    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = 1+i;

    clock_t t;

    t = clock();

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        matrix[i][i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j< N; j++)
            if (j != i)
                matrix[i][i] += sin(cos(log(matrix[i][j] + matrix[j][i])));
    }
    t = clock() - t;

    std::cout << "It took " << ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " sec" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It works correctly and uses 2 threads. However, it loads 2 processors (~100% CPU) and takes the same time (~34 seconds) as the similiar consequtive one (loads 1 processor ~50% CPU). I know that OpenMP may need some time to start, but how can it result in the same duration of programs?

Comment: Do **not** use `clock` to measure parallel run time. It has been treated here perhaps thousand times...

Comment: These are two different questions and should be asked separately. The OpenMP part is clearly a duplicate of **many** other questions here.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to the MPI part of the question.
Do you have MPICH installed? If is that so, try to compile and run like this:

```
$ mpicc.mpich mpi_hello.c -o hello    
$ mpirun.mpich -np 4 ./hello          
I am 0 from 4
I am 1 from 4
I am 2 from 4
I am 3 from 4
```

It should work.